# Function props with functional component - is not a function (React + TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a functional component with a function prop that does not work. So...

```
export interface IPanelProps {
  itemID; number;
  Open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
}


const FabricPanel: FC<IPanelProps> = ({ onClose, Open, itemID }) => {
  let _OnCancelClick = () => {
    onClose();
  }

  return (
    <Panel isOpen={Open}>
      <h2>{itemID} </h2>
      <DialogFooter>
        <DefaultButton text="Cancel" onClick={_OnCancelClick} />
        <PrimaryButton text="Save" />
      </DialogFooter>
    </Panel>
  )
}
```

Getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: onClose is not a function

Open and Item ID props are working just fine, is it because I am calling a function prop? I have tried to put (props) instead and this did not work.

How can I fix this?

On the parent component:

```
   _renderPanelComponent = (props: any) => {
    const element : React.ReactElement<IPanelProps> = React.createElement(FabricPanel, assign({
      itemID : null,
      Open : false,
      OnClose : null
      

    }, props))
    ReactDom.render(element, this.panelPlaceHolder);
  }

  _showPanel = (itemID : number) => {
    this._renderPanelComponent({
      itemID,
      Open : true,
      OnClose : this._dismissPanel
      
      
    })
  }

  _dismissPanel = () =>{        
    this._renderPanelComponent({ isOpen: false });   
 }
```

When a button is pressed on SharePoint the arrow function `Showpanel` is executed and this works fine, but the `onClose` doesn't work.

Comment: This looks fine. Typescript recognizes it is a function. `TypeError` happens at runtime - it looks like `onClose` isn't defined, or is not a function. Try debugging what `onClose` is at run time (i.e `console.log(onClose)`)

Comment: there's a typo `itemID;` should be `itemID:`. although everything else looks fine. can u `console.log(typeof onClose)`?

Comment: when i console log onClose it comes back as undefined ?? Why is this ?

Comment: @Jason_Hough because you are passing nothing from the parent component. whoever is using `<FabricPanel />` must pass `onClose` property which is a `function`. For example, `<FabricPanel onClose={() => {}} />`

Comment: @deadcoder0904 - I have updated the issue with some of the parent component.. I get what your saying completely, can you have 2 mins to have a look please ?

Comment: @Jason_Hough you have assigned `OnClose : null` which you cannot do for a function. a function's signature is `() => null` if you really don't want to return `null` from the function or you can do `() => void` if it returns nothing :)

Answer (score 1):

OnClose is spelt differently between the functional component and the parent comonent. So both are spelt onClose - sorted!